# Visual Studio Problem

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

When I open File -> New Website from the main window, New website prompt comes empty. There is nothing to select. Do I have a configuration or installation error?

Installed Products:

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.30729.1 SP Microsoft .NET Framework Version 3.5 SP1

Installed Edition: IDE Standard

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB945282) KB945282 This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU. If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB946040) KB946040 This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU. If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB946308) KB946308 This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU. If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB946344) KB946344 This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU. If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB946581) KB946581 This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU. If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB947173) KB947173 This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU. If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB947540) KB947540 This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU. If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB947789) KB947789 This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU. If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

SQL Server Analysis Services
Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services Designer Version 10.0.1600.22

SQL Server Integration Services
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer Version 10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )

SQL Server Reporting Services
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers Version 10.0.1600.22

Comment: If you go to Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio, what appears in Installed Products list? Click Copy Info button and paste into your question.

Comment: This question really belongs on superuser...

Comment: First question is are you using a legitimate copy of VS?  If you are, you might want to try installing ASP.net on your local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Installed Products:**

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5 SP1

Installed Edition: IDE Standard

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB945282)   KB945282
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB946040)   KB946040
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB946308)   KB946308
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB946344)   KB946344
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB946581)   KB946581
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB947173)   KB947173
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB947540)   KB947540
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU (KB947789)   KB947789
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled automatically.

SQL Server Analysis Services
Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services Designer 
Version 10.0.1600.22

SQL Server Integration Services
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )

SQL Server Reporting Services
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers 
Version 10.0.1600.22

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the Microsoft Visual Web Developer version of Visual Studio installed. I think your installation was installed as part of a SQL Server 2008 installation. You need to install the full version. Or you could try the Express Version.

Have a look at my installation details below:

Installed Edition: Professional

Microsoft Visual Basic 2008   91605-270-4301094-60471
Microsoft Visual Basic 2008

Microsoft Visual C# 2008   91605-270-4301094-60471
Microsoft Visual C# 2008

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office   91605-270-4301094-60471
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office

Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008   91605-270-4301094-60471
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008

...Other hotfixes plugins removed ...